# Foreign key references one of many tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a structure like this:

**Sport**:

```
reference int identity not null, primary key (ID),
Duration int, --e.g. football is 90 minutes
Players int,
SportID int,
SportType int --0 for football and 1 for tennis
```

**Tennis**

```
Reference int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
TurfType int,
-- + more fields related to Tennis
```

**Football**:

```
Reference int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
-- + more fields related to Football
```

`Sport.SportID` references either Tennis or Football or Gymnastics etc. The only way I can think of doing this is having a `SportType` in the `Sport` table to say what table `Sport.SportID` references.

This doesn't look right though. Is this the best approach?

Comment: This is a horrible approach. Since you're "referencing" one of several table, you basically **cannot** reference anything. You should turn the relationships around : `Tennis` should reference `Sport`, `Football` should reference `Sport` - then you'll have **real**, enforceable referential integrity constraints!

Comment: @marc_s, that would mean that Sport has a FootballID, TennisID etc.  There would be lots of nulls.

Comment: Yes - and so what?? Null's don't hurt.... At least that way, you have **real** integrity - not just a *looking like* integrity that's worth nothing...

Comment: Why not have a sportsassocTable -> sportid , tennisid, footballid and have Check that only one value can be set and also referential integrity can be maintained

Comment: @marc_s, thanks.  Do you prefer your approach to the approach suggested by Gordon Linoff in his answer?

Comment: No, Gordon's approach is basically the same - except he keeps the `SportType` column. The main thing is: you need **one FK column** for each sport type that you want to support for **proper referential integrity** - you cannot reference "one out of n different tables" with a single FK column and have proper integrity with that.

Comment: @marc_s, thanks.  Can you answer my question in my comment under Gordons answer?

Answer (score 2):

Having a `SportType` column is reasonable.  You can approach this using a structure such as:

```
create table Sports (
    SportsId int identity not null, primary key (ID),
    Duration int, --e.g. football is 90 minutes
    Players int,
    SportType varchar(10),
    SportId int,
    check (SportType in ('Football', 'Tennis'),
    FootballId as (case when SportType = 'Football' then SportId end),
    TennisId as (case when SportType = 'Tennis' then SportId end),
    foreign key (FootballId) references Football(FootballId),
    foreign key (Tennis) references Tennis(Tennis)
);
```

Note that this uses computed columns for the foreign key reference to ensure referential integrity.

Comment: Thanks +1.  Say SportID was a footballID.  How would I do an inner join between Sport and Football to return all the fields from both tables?

Comment: @w0051977 . . . You would use the computed column `FootballId` for the `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to give the name of a sport, so that the database displays the details(duration, type of field played on, number of players etc)?

Comment: Yes.  This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @w0051977 He can not comment given his reputation

Comment: @Begueradj, that's fair enough.  Just don't answer unless you have an anwer.